# Laravel query with condition from table value

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to query from a table which has column name 'is_reviewed', when the value of 'is_reviewed' is 0, then query this table, if the value is "1", then query from other table, is that possible to do that?

Im using Laravel 5.5, right now im just using if else and this is not working.

```
$isReviewed = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->select(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN is_reviewed = 0 THEN "0" ELSE "1" END)'))->get();

if ($isReviewed == '0') {
    $datas = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('projects.status', 2)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'project_users.user_id')
        ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_users.project_id')
        ->join('websites_list', 'websites_list.id', '=', 'projects.id_website')
        ->select('projects.*', 'websites_list.url_web', 'users.name', 'project_users.user_id')
        ->whereNotIn('is_reviewed', [1])
        ->get();
} elseif ($isReviewed == '1') {
    $datas = ReviewProjectUser::where('reviewer_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('projects.status', 2)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'review_project_users.reviewer_user_id')
        ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'review_project_users.project_uid')
        ->join('websites_list', 'websites_list.id', '=', 'projects.id_website')
        ->select('projects.*', 'websites_list.url_web', 'users.name', 'review_project_users.reviewer_user_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you tryin' to get an array result in you query or just one row. If your expected result in your query is just one row then don't use the `->get()` try `->first()` instead.

Using `->get()` returns `$isReviewed` as array.

Try using `->first()` in your query. like this.

Anyway, to simplify your query here is the eloquent way.

```
$isReviewed = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

if ($isReviewed->is_reviewed == '0') 
{
    //your code
}
else if($isReviewed->is_reviewed == '1') 
{
    //your code
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is works, but what i expexted is the data from ProjectUser model and ReviewProjectUser model, the ```is_reviewed``` column is in the ProjectUser. If value of ```is_reviewed``` is 0, then return whole ProjectUser, but if it value is 1, then return ReviewProjectUser table. I hope u understand my case..

Comment: @BagasAlfiandhiNugroho, meaning there is no problem in your first query. The main problem is on the condition `if/else` query? am i right?

Comment: Yeah, youre right. Right now im just querying both table and return it on the different view. What i want is with that condition, i get the different query. I wondering is that possible? Because the first query for the condition is for each row on the table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your SQL Statement is wrong. That's why your `IF` does not work.

Secound, you dont need to use `sql case` while `is_reviewed` in your `ProjectUser` is already have a static value.

Based on [Laravel - Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#retrieving-results)

You can use

```
$isReviewed = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->value('is_reviewed');
```

Your `$isReviewed` will only return the value of your field, then you just need to combine the if statement.

```
if ($isReviewed == '0') {
    $datas = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('projects.status', 2)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'project_users.user_id')
        ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'project_users.project_id')
        ->join('websites_list', 'websites_list.id', '=', 'projects.id_website')
        ->select('projects.*', 'websites_list.url_web', 'users.name', 'project_users.user_id')
        ->whereNotIn('is_reviewed', [1])
        ->get();
} elseif ($isReviewed == '1') {
    $datas = ReviewProjectUser::where('reviewer_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('projects.status', 2)
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'review_project_users.reviewer_user_id')
        ->join('projects', 'projects.id', '=', 'review_project_users.project_uid')
        ->join('websites_list', 'websites_list.id', '=', 'projects.id_website')
        ->select('projects.*', 'websites_list.url_web', 'users.name', 'review_project_users.reviewer_user_id')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

In your query below laravel returns an array of results,

```
$isReviewed = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) ->select(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN is_reviewed = 0 THEN "0" ELSE "1" END)'))->get();
```

If you `dd($isReviewd)` you'll see your result is an array of `ProjectUser`.

So, in this case you're selecting single row, you can limit your query by adding `->first()` to the end of your query and now your variable is an instance of `ProjectUser`

At the end, call -`>is_reviewd` to access your variable.

**In conclusion**
Your query should like this:

```
$isReviewed = ProjectUser::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) ->select(DB::raw('(CASE WHEN is_reviewed = 0 THEN "0" ELSE "1" END)'))->first()->is_reviewd;
```

Comment: any the sql case statement was wrong, if u `dd($isReviewd)` will be return the sql statement, however why you are using ->get() then using ->first() is goind to return an error